# Date Difference in JavaScript with Timezone

Tags: javascript

I am very new in javascript and trying get day difference with set timezone.
My script is like below

```js
let localCurrentDate = new Date();
let booking_date = '06/11/2020';
var inputdate = booking_date + ' ' + '00:00:00 UTC+2';
const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
// date eg; "006/15/2020 00:00:00 UTC+2"
var utc2Date = inputdate;
let parsedDate = new Date(utc2Date);
//let currentDate = new Date();
let curDate = new Date(localCurrentDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: "Europe/Rome"
}));
let diffTime = Math.abs(curDate - parsedDate);
let diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / oneDay);
//return diffDays;
console.log("input date" + parsedDate);
console.log("current date" + curDate);
console.log("day difference: " +diffDays);
```

But since I am setting time 00:00:00 with my input date, and current time getting current time, so difference is coming +1 day . Can I know how I can get day difference with void time? or how I can set time as 00:00:00 with getting current date? I want set and use timezone with it.
Thanks!

Comment: what exactly you want is not very clear

Comment: @ABGR I want get day difference between input date and current date, since I am getting current date with current time and I have input date without time so I am setting 00:00:00 as time with input date and thats the reason I am getting +1 day difference.

Comment: You could set the current time to 00:00:00 after you receive the input from the user.

Comment: @AshikPaul I am doing same currently and thats causing issue, because input have 00:00:00 time and current have real time.

Comment: For what it's worth `06/11/2020` is a non-standard date string. I suggest using `2020-06-11` or `2020-11-06`

Comment: @ABGR it will have also same issue because of time, not?

Comment: @ABGR I am very new in javascript and not getting idea how I can do it :( sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting your `inputdate` to `UTC` date and then use `new Date()` to get `inputdate` object to get in current timezone. Then you can get `difference`.

Updated code `let parsedDate = new Date((new Date(utc2Date)).toUTCString());`.

Check it below.

```js
let localCurrentDate = new Date();
let booking_date = '2020-06-12';
var inputdate = booking_date + ' ' + '00:00:00 UTC+2';
const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
// date eg; "006/15/2020 00:00:00 UTC+2"
var utc2Date = inputdate;
let parsedDate = new Date((new Date(utc2Date)).toUTCString());
//let currentDate = new Date();
let curDate = new Date();
let diffTime = Math.abs(curDate - parsedDate);
let diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / oneDay);
//return diffDays;
console.log("input date" + parsedDate);
console.log("current date" + curDate);
console.log("day difference: " +diffDays);
```

In case if you want to get difference from date only without considering time (set time to `00:00:00.000`) then use `date.setHours(0,0,0,0);`.

Here is the code snippet.

```js
let localCurrentDate = new Date();
let booking_date = '2020-06-12';
var inputdate = booking_date + ' ' + '00:00:00 UTC+2';
const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
// date eg; "006/15/2020 00:00:00 UTC+2"
var utc2Date = inputdate;
let parsedDate = new Date((new Date(utc2Date)).toUTCString());
//let currentDate = new Date();
let curDate = new Date();
curDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);   // set time to 00:00:00.000
parsedDate.setHours(0,0,0,0); // set time to 00:00:00.000
let diffTime = Math.abs(curDate - parsedDate);
let diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / oneDay);
//return diffDays;
console.log("input date" + parsedDate);
console.log("current date" + curDate);
console.log("day difference: " +diffDays);
```

Comment: Thanks for it. when run code I am getting day difference: NaN, can you please look in it? Thanks!

Comment: I am using it as 06/11/2020 and its working fine, since you have removed timezone from current date, it will not cause issue? Thanks!

Comment: This is awesome, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to adjust the dates to `getTimezoneOffset` and then compare.

So let's say you  want to compare `Date A` with time zone Indian Standard Time (+ 5:30) with another date `Date B` with different time zone, say with (+ 2:30).

What you need to do here is bring both of these dates to their UTC date and time and then compare. `getTimezoneOffset()` will give you the minutes past the `UTC` time. If you set this in the minutes you'll have normalise the date to `UTC` date and time. If you set both the dates with `getTimezoneOffset()`, you'll be able to compare them easily.

```
var d = new Date();

d.setMinutes(d.getTimezoneOffset());
```

simlarly,

```
inputDate.setMinutes(inputDate.getTimezoneOffset())
```

```js
let localCurrentDate = new Date();

let curDate = new Date(localCurrentDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: "Europe/Rome"
}));

curDate.setMinutes(curDate.getTimezoneOffset());
localCurrentDate.setMinutes(localCurrentDate.getTimezoneOffset());

var diff = Math.abs(localCurrentDate - curDate);
const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
   
console.log(diff/oneDay)
```

Comment: I think I am not clear in my requirement. in my code UTC 2 and Europe/Rome are same timezone, since I have input have always time as 00:00:00 and current time have real time like 15:22:33 and thats the reason I am not getting perfect day difference in it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Typescript version (in milliseconds):

```
export const timeDiffMs = (
  timeA: Date | string,
  timeB: Date | string
): number => {
  timeA = new Date(
    (typeof timeA === "Date" ? timeA : new Date(timeA)).toUTCString()
  );
  timeB = new Date(
    (typeof timeB === "Date" ? timeB : new Date(timeB)).toUTCString()
  );

  return timeA.getTime() - timeB.getTime();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
            let currDate = new Date();
            let bookingDate = window.document.getElementById("bookingDate");
            let olddate = bookingDate.value;
            
            let isChanged = function(){
                if(bookingDate.value!== olddate){
                    olddate = bookingDate.value;
                    return true;
                };
                return false;
            };
            
            bookingDate.addEventListener("blur", function(){
                
              if(isChanged()){
                    
                    bDate = new Date(bookingDate.value);
                    
                    let diffTime = Math.abs(bDate - currDate);
                    let diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 

                    alert(diffDays + " days");
              }
                
            });
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Date Difference in JavaScript with Timezone</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <h3>Select Date</h3>
        <input type="date" id="bookingDate" >
        <input type="button" value="Get Date Difference" >
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want only set input date manually, current date I want get from system, you have set both manually, can You modify my code as answer? Thanks!

Comment: you need to take just input field and take it's value in javascript, i edit my answer you.